# Авторизация Angularjs + Spring security

Tags: angularjs, spring, безопасность

Не могу найти какой-либо внятной и полноценной документации или работающий пример где angularjs авторизуется на restful spring security приложении. При этом время жизни сессии/токена должно быть ограничено.

Каким образом реализовать самый простой пример кода, создающего такую связку, чтобы было от чего отталкиваться?

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос, привёл его, как мне кажется, в соответствие с онтопиком на сайте.

Comment: спасибо, надеюсь получить какой-либо ответ.

Comment: вопрос именно в связке, когда есть работающее ангуляр приложение и работающее restful spring security приложение и нужно их только связать или нужно пример каждой части?

Comment: А чем вам форм аутентификация не подходит для этого? Создаёте форму, шлете реквестор получаете куки. Что ещё надо? Эти кейсы хорошо описаны в документации